# logstash data import status

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I have developed a Java EE Application using Apache Solr and now i want to migrate into elasticsearch.
I have converted my api to use elasticsearch instead of solr but i have a big problem
I don`t know how to get last data import status from logstash.
In apache Solr mode i can get data import status from solr easily using:

- Query type: dataimport
- Command: status

and i can get last update time, total imported documents count, import status , time taken , ...
So, how can i implement this feature using elasticsearch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since version 5, Logstash now provides [monitoring APIs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/monitoring.html) that you cas use to gets some insights into how many events have flown through Logstash since the last restart. Granted it's not the same as what Solr gave you.

Otherwise, you may use the [`_cat/indices`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cat-indices.html) endpoint in order to discover how many documents are currently indexed into each index of your cluster. That won't give you any timing information like last update time and time taken, but the current document count will be provided.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I am going to use it.
But do you have any idea to get information about last update time?

Comment: If your documents have a timestamp field, you can sort on it and get the latest document, that gives you an indication about the last update time